# Is it possible to return coordinates as arrays rather than strings using ogr?

Tags: coordinates, ogr

I am trying to convert a list of coordinates between CRS's using gdal's Python bindings. I would like to have the converted coordinates output as an array, but I can only seem to export as various types of strings.

```
import ogr
import osr
import numpy as np

xs = np.array([11705274.6374, 10705274.6374]) 
ys = np.array([4826473.6922, 4856473.6922])

# Spatial Reference System
inputEPSG = 3857
outputEPSG = 4326

# Create an ogr object of multipoints
points = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiPoint)
for i in range(len(xs)):
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(float(xs[i]), float(ys[i]))
    points.AddGeometry(point)

# Create coordinate transformation
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(inputEPSG)

outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(outputEPSG)

coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)

# transform point
points.Transform(coordTransform)

points.FlattenTo2D()
print(points.ExportToWkt())

MULTIPOINT (105.15027111593 39.7278572772792,96.1671182747348 39.9348108861792)
```

The xs and ys provided are just dummy points I randomly typed. I am casting them as numpy arrays as my program will be providing them as such.

I can break the MULTIPOINT string up and pull the coordinates, but this is undesirable as it may cost precision and is just clunky. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I am providing an answer that does the job, but I still feel confident this should be achievable without a loop.

```
xyout = np.array([0,0])
for i in range(len(xs)):
    xyout = np.vstack((xyout, points.GetGeometryRef(i).GetPoints()))
xyout = xyout[1:,:]
```